# How to easily use remote ssh of vscode to connect to different server with the same IP via differet jump machine?

Tags: ssh, vscode-remote

I now have 2 jump machine `AJ` and `BJ`, with different IP. Each jump machine connects to a target machine `AT` and `BT`, with the same IP. I'm using vscode 1.87.2 on windows 10, and I want to connect to `AT` and `BT`. Below is my `.ssh\config`

```
Host AJ
  HostName 10.0.2.11
  User mon
  Port 22

Host AT
  HostName 172.20.21.21
  User mon
  Port 22
  ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe  -W %h:%p AJ


Host BJ
  HostName 10.0.2.12
  User mon
  Port 22

Host BT
  HostName 172.20.21.21
  User mon
  Port 22
  ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -W %h:%p BJ
```

It works well, however, if I use `AT` first, then I need to connect to `BT`, vscode would tell me that it can't establish connection with `BT` because `Host key verification failed`. I need to delete the line of `AT` in `.ssh\known_host`, only after then I can connect to `BT`. Of course first `BT` and then `AT` would be the same. The first time when I connect to a target machine, it would let me to ensure fingerprint, and a new line starts with "172.20.21.21" would be written in `known_hosts`. Then if I need to connect to a different target machine, "172.20.21.21" would have different fingerprint, then connection fails.

I think that's too troublesome, and I noticed that in the output it said `ECDSA host key for 172.20.21.21 has changed and you have requested strict checking`, so I changed the `ProxyCommand` to

```
  ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile=C:\NonExistentFile" -W %h:%p AJ/BJ
```

But it doesn't work, it still says `you have requested strict checking`, so now I don't know how to solve this problem. I don't want to globally disable strict hostkey checking, but just want to disable it when I need to connect to target servers with the same IP.